# Trying to select link on navbar and show that it's active

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I would like to click "Page 1" on the top navbar on the following link, which would make the "Page 1" value on the filter bar active and highlighted. How can I do this?

Please see the jfiddle example:  https://jsfiddle.net/qtcz2guk/1/

### JavaScript

```
$('.nav a').click(function(){
$(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');   
});
```

### CSS

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, 
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
color: #d65c14;
background: #000;
}
```

### HTML

```
<title>Bootstrap Case</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">WebSiteName</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctiona(); return false">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctionb(); return false">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctionc(); return false">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>
  <p>A navigation bar is placed at the top of the page.</p>
  <p>A filter bar is placed in the middle of the page.</p>
  <p>Question: How can i make this work so that clicking "Page 1" on the top navbar makes the filter bar "Page 1" to be active and highlighted?</p>
  </h3> 
</div>


<div class="container">
<div id="menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-custom">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctionall(); return false">FILTER BY /</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctiona(); return false">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctionb(); return false">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="myFunctionc(); return false">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Please include some samples of what you want.

Comment: please see this jfiddle example;  https://jsfiddle.net/qtcz2guk/1/